# PHP Validate Cost Amount 2 Decimal Places

Tags: php, validation

My api requires all data related to subscription costs be in the correct format before being committed to the DB as customers will be charged the amount. The following rules apply.

1. Must be numeric with no currency symbols. Validating using `is_string($data['cost'])`
2. Cannot be a negative amount. Validating using `$data['cost'] < 0`
3. Must have two decimal places, even when the amount has no cents ($100.00).

What would be the best way to go about validating requirement #3?

Comment: What kind of column are you using?

Comment: Using DECIMAL for all currency amounts.

Comment: So what does it matter if I send you `100` or `100.00`? You're going to store it as `100.00` either way… You're making your API difficult to use.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree with you on that point. I made an assumption that validating decimal points would result in forcing .00 to be present. The main issue is how to go about restricting the submitted amount on the php side? If I get an amount of 100.235 and let it through I'll get 100.24 in the db. I need to block it from getting through and validate only two decimal places.

Comment: Are you accepting the value as a string, or a number?

Comment: A number. If it comes in as a string I catch it with 'is_string($data['cost'])'

Comment: So you are doing this way to prevent rounding?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Decided to go with something pretty straight forward. If a decimal is present in the cost, check how many places to the right. Otherwise commit to DB.

```
$amount = explode('.', $data['cost']);
if(isset($amount[1]) && strlen($amount[1]) > 2) {
   // response  
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. It should be `strlen($amount[1]) == 2)` because you want to check for exactly 2 figures after the decimal point. The code you've written means "more than 2 figures after the decimal", denoted by `> 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). <s>The advantage is that no matter what you get (not enough 0s or too many 0s) it will save it in the correct format</s>

```
number_format("1000000",2) // 1,000,000.00
```

**Edit:** To use this for validation,

```
$num = $data['cost'];
$check = number_format($num,2);
if ($num == $check) return true;
```

Comment: Question is about validation. Your code basically does the opposite: let everything pass through.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - _"Must have two decimal places, even when the amount has no cents ($100.00)."_ So OP want the user to always type in down to two decimal places?

Comment: That's what I understand. Please check OP's comment below question about blocking `100.235`.

Answer (score 0):

I made an improvement based on Runicode's solution:

```
function is_price($price) {
    $amount = explode('.', $price);
    if (ctype_digit($amount[0]) and substr($amount[0],0,1)!='0') {
        if (isset($amount[1]) && (strlen($amount[1])!=2 or (!ctype_digit($amount[1])))) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Works with both prices without cents and prices with cents.
It also return false for prices with leading zero.

The function parameter can be either string, int or float

Example:

10.50 -> return true

12450 -> return true

3532.08 -> return true

10.4 -> return false

10. -> return false

0123.21 -> return false

102 32.12 -> return false

432asd.34 -> return false

asddas -> return false